# Multiple set operations - which will be performed last?

Tags: firebase

I have to sync file with firebase when it changes. I know how to set up handler when file changes and then call `Firebase.set`. But what will happen if file is quite big (9mb) and it takes 30 seconds for example for `set` operation to finish and in the mean time file changes again? What happens when set on some locations is in progress and second set on the same location is performed?

1. Fb will automatically cancel in-progress operation and start it again?
2. Or it will wait till in-progress opeartion is finished and then start it again?
3. Or it will be the best to monitor if set on goven location is if progress, and if it is then  queue next set operation after the in-progress finishes?

---

sample test

```
ref1 = new Firebase('https://my_firebase.firebaseio.com/some_location')
ref2 = new Firebase('https://my_firebase.firebaseio.com/some_location')
ref1.set({ some_large_data: 'abcef...' });
ref2.set({ some_large_data: '12345...' });
// which set will take effect on server? second? Or random (second that actually completes)?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the tests it seems that **Firebase will perform all `set` operations on server sequentialy one after another, without cancelling any of them  even when next one is done locally before previous completed remotely**

This means that if you call `set()` 100 times, each set operation will affect remote data (database). For my use case this is bad because on every file change it will be entirely uploaded to firebase. I will have to write my own algorithm that will decide when to sync data with firebase.

Test consists of two scripts - one is writing data to same firebase location multiple times and second one is reading data from that location.

set_data.coffee

```
Firebase = require 'firebase'
firebaseUrl = 'https://my_firebase.firebaseio.com/same_location'

ref1 = new Firebase firebaseUrl
ref2 = new Firebase firebaseUrl
ref3 = new Firebase firebaseUrl

ref1.on 'value', (snapshot) -> console.log 'local same_location changed to ' + Buffer.byteLength((snapshot.val() or ''), 'utf8') + ' bytes'

data1 = ''
data2 = ''
data3 = ''
data1 += '1' for i in [1..1000*1000*2]
data2 += '2' for i in [1..1000*1000*3]
data3 += '3' for i in [1..100]

console.log 'data1 ' + Buffer.byteLength(data1, 'utf8') + ' bytes'
console.log 'data2 ' + Buffer.byteLength(data2, 'utf8') + ' bytes'
console.log 'data3 ' + Buffer.byteLength(data3, 'utf8') + ' bytes'

t1 = new Date()
ref1.set data1, (err) ->
  elapsed = new Date().getTime() - t1.getTime()
  console.log 'set1 finished ('+elapsed+'ms) - err is '+err
t2 = new Date()
ref2.set data2, (err) ->
  elapsed = new Date().getTime() - t2.getTime()
  console.log 'set2 finished ('+elapsed+'ms) - err is '+err
t3 = new Date()
ref3.set data3, (err) ->
  elapsed = new Date().getTime() - t3.getTime()
  console.log 'set3 finished ('+elapsed+'ms) - err is '+err
```

get_data.coffee

```
Firebase = require 'firebase'

firebaseUrl = 'https://my_firebase.firebaseio.com/same_location'

ref1 = new Firebase firebaseUrl

ref1.on 'value', (snapshot) -> console.log 'remote same_location changed to ' + Buffer.byteLength((snapshot.val() or ''), 'utf8') + ' bytes'
```

output from set_data.coffee

```
data1 2000000 bytes
data2 3000000 bytes
data3 100 bytes
local same_location changed to 2000000 bytes
local same_location changed to 3000000 bytes
local same_location changed to 100 bytes
set1 finished (118314ms) - err is null
set2 finished (149844ms) - err is null
set3 finished (149845ms) - err is null
```

output from get_data.coffee

```
remote same_location changed to 0 bytes
remote same_location changed to 2000000 bytes
remote same_location changed to 3000000 bytes
remote same_location changed to 100 bytes
```

Comment: This may well be true if the 100 ops are performed synchronously by the same client. But there are no guarantees that two async events sent over the web will arrive at the server in the same order they were initiated. This is particularly true of multiple clients, where they do not share a socket connection and where Firebase can't optimize the operations or queue them in a specific order.

Comment: Yes but single fb client just queues each `set` in FIFO-like queue and each set is executed after the previous one finished.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your question is about this flow:

1. client A starts uploading a huge file
2. client B start uploading a smaller file
3. client B's upload completes
4. client A's upload completes

Firebase's servers will handle the updates transactionally, so no partial updates will ever occur.

The last update to (completely) reach the Firebase server, is the one that will end up in the node.

If you want control over this type of concurrent access, you're probably better of using a worker queue. Of course Firebase is extremely well suited for synchronizing access to such a worker queue too. :-)

So in the flow above, no writing to your Firebase node will occur on the server until after step 3. After step 4, Firebase will write the huge file and "forgot" that the smaller file from client B ever existed. If you want to prevent such unintended overwriting, you could consider step 0 being "Client locks the upload location with a `transaction` call". This would essentially implement pessimistic locking on top of Firebase's optimistic locking approach.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but it not exactly what I wanted to know. In my scenario SAME client starts uploading file to location A and before it is finished he upload data AGAIN to SAME location. How Firebase will treat this situation? I guess it applies first upload locally and then second upload locally. But what about two uploads that didn't finished yet? The one that ends second will be actual? Or Firebase somehow magically knows that on the same client ALWAYS second set to same location should update database? - I have updated question with sample code

Comment: OK, that is indeed different. Although on the server it would be the exact same, so there is still no change of data corruption. On the client it is interesting whether the second `set` will cancel the first one (which I think it *does not*). You might be able to easily test this if you enable debug logging in the client: `Firebase.enableLogging(true, true);` See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21611103/209103

Comment: Keep in mind btw that the communication from the Firebase client to the server is sequential (at least on any protocol I'm aware of). So it may well function as option #3, even though it's not explicitly defined like that.

Comment: Ok so it seems I have to test it. But do you think that when I call `set` (for same lcoation) 100 times in for loop, each one setting a lot of data, then Firebase will sequentially perform each of those 100 "uploads"?

Comment: There is one way to find out: try it! I do wonder what use-case you have for that functionality, but regardless of that: it'll be an interesting experiment.

Comment: Use case is syncing files from directory to Firebase - when file changes I call set(). File my change again before first upload completes. It is possible to just store informations about which file is syncing right now with fb and wait till it finishes - but maybe Firebase does it out of the box :)? I will test it today and post my results